# Построение графа, визуализация базы данных (mysql) и их взаимосвязей используя Python

Tags: c#, mysql, python, база-данных, визуализация

Использую Python 3.5 под Anaconda (Windows 8).

Есть база данных MySQL5, в ней есть большое количество данных вида:

**ID**, **ID-другого пользователя**, **Принято (число)**, **Отправлено (число)**.

Данные между собой могут как пересекаться, так и не пересекаться, образуя отдельные "хабы" взаимодействия. Хочу визуализировать это как в MindMap (пример транзакций между пользователями).

В принципе нет разницы - где получить вывод в QT окошке, или на сайте.

Данных действительно много (база мегабайт 50-100) и размер картинки может быть внушительный в отличии от моего иллюстрирующего примера (тут нужен совет где меньше ресурсов машины съест и не скушает всю память ли, выводиться это будет не для большого количества пользователей а для меня).

**Вопрос:** Какую библиотеку \ (инструмент в QT)  возможно использовать которая(ый) может сделать дерево взаимосвязи в продемонстрированном примере (рисунок), взаимодействуя с БД. Предпочтение конечно к простоте в реализации, установки библиотеки и взаимодействию с ней.

P.S.: если для Python нет готового модуля (а написать такой как я понял требует много сил и умений, возможно подойдут варианты на MS Visual C#).

[image: пример визуализации данных в виде "mindmap"]

**Update:**
 1. Пока ждал ответов, и советов наткнулся на это: https://gephi.org/ из статьи https://habrahabr.ru/post/136575/ . Но это кажется более сложным решением, по крайней мере "чрезмерным".

2. http://www.graphviz.org/ , туториал http://matthiaseisen.com/articles/graphviz/
3. https://github.com/pmatiello/python-graph
4. http://gato.sourceforge.net/
5. http://networkx.github.io/ статья на хабре https://habrahabr.ru/post/125898/ https://habrahabr.ru/post/129344/
6. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ps5RtmWKwLY Holger Spill: An introduction to Python and graph databases with Neo4j
7. http://orange.biolab.si/screenshots/ - устанавливается вместе с Anaconda

Comment: Я не знаток работы с базами данных, но можно ли загрузить её, выделить не взаимосвязанные подсети (или пусть даже взаимосвязанные, чтобы не слишком уж крупные были), их уже отдельно отрисовывать при помощи GraphViz? Этот инструмент действительно мощный, сотни элементов может качественно обрабатывать.